# How to avoid fragment's list refreshing after Navigation Drawer opens?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have list in my fragment and NavigationDrawer in MainActivity. From NavigationDrawer I'm calling that fragment. When I have scrolled a little bit and opened NavigationDrawer again, list refreshes and starts from the top. I guess the main reason is `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` because when I comment this line everything is okay, but my Search in ActionBar doesn't work.

When I have scrolled a little bit:[image]

What it should look like:[image]

What it's actually looks:
[image]

My fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alllists, container, false);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.small_icon);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    position = bundle.getInt("position");
    location = bundle.getString("location");
    image.setImageDrawable(navMenuIcons.getDrawable(position));
    context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    items = db.getAllItems(location);
    tmp_items = db.getAllItems(location);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, items);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, "", false);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, tmp_items);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            if (tmp_s.length() > s.length()) {
                adapter.getFilter(tmp_items, true).filter(s);
            } else {
                adapter.getFilter(tmp_items, false).filter(s);
            }
            tmp_s = s;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
}
```

**I have updated my newInstance method:**

```
public static final AllLists newInstance(int position, String location) {
    AllLists mainfrag = MainActivity.getMainFragment();
    if (mainfrag == null || !mainfrag.getArguments().getString("location").equals(location)) {
        AllLists all = new AllLists();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(2);
        bdl.putInt("position", position);
        bdl.putString("location", location);
        all.setArguments(bdl);
        MainActivity.setMainFragment(all);
        return all;
    }
    return mainfrag;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public static AllLists mainFragment = null;

 ...

public static void setMainFragment(AllLists fragment) {
    mainFragment = fragment;
}

public static AllLists getMainFragment() {
    return mainFragment;
}
```

Just to be clear, I change my fragments like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
       .beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.frame_container, AllLists.newInstance(position, location))
       .commit();
```

Comment: I really like the blurs and the handbag icon (looks like a face)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Fragment View will get reset each time you return to it.

To not to loose state of your main fragment, you should do "new Fragment()" only once in your newIntance method. You can make a global variable, say 'mainFragment', storing once created new Fragment(), and then apply a check that if your global variable, i.e. 'mainFragment', is not null, then return mainFragment.

This should fix your problem. But on screen rotations, a new instance will still be created, leading to again taking you back to top of your list. For the rotation problem, see :

http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/06/navigationdrawer-creates-fragment-twice.html

Comment: Sorry for a delay, I'm not sure am I doing everything properly. I have updated my newInstance method, but the problem hasn't vanished.

Comment: First of all you need to keep a global variable for instantiated fragment. I think you have made a local variable, if I am not wrong. plz correct it, and plz go through the link in my answer, that will solve all your problem, not only rotation related but also can be used for the problem you mentioned.

Comment: I went through that link but I didn't find it relevant in my case. I have updated my question and added my MainActivity's methods, where I set and get my fragment.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, you have done everything correctly according to me. If you can share, plz upload to github your code and may be I can replicate it and may provide more help, thx. Would love to help...

Comment: Have a look at all you need to know about fragments : https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial       Plz read `Saving Fragment State` topic in the link. It says that by default all fragments are saved if they have ids and one can override it.

Comment: I checked that link, but I still haven't got any ideas why my code doesn't work or how to accomplish it with a new method. I can provide my MainActivity's code in github: https://github.com/miestomeniu/MiestoMeniu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/miesto/meniu/MainActivity.java and also Alllists.java (my main fragment): https://github.com/miestomeniu/MiestoMeniu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/miesto/meniu/AllLists.java. I would be really happy if you could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have been busy... I will soon look again from your mentioned github repos, but I can't promise success, but will give it a try.

Comment: Hey, maybe you had a look at that? Unfortunately, GitHub link had changed so I will paste my code with pastebin. My MainActivity's code: http://pastebin.com/6pW85ULy and also Alllists.java (my main fragment): http://pastebin.com/eUMEQC7J

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar),

> Your fragments can contribute menu items to the activity's Options
>   Menu (and, consequently, the Action Bar) by implementing
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(). In order for this method to receive calls,
>   however, you must call setHasOptionsMenu() during onCreate(), to
>   indicate that the fragment would like to add items to the Options Menu
>   (otherwise, the fragment will not receive a call to
>   onCreateOptionsMenu()).

so, lets move move the `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` from your `onCreateView(...)` call to the `onCreate(...)` override in your fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```